# Python way of merging two dictionnaries based on a common value?

Tags: python

Given two dictionnaries:

```
a = {
    'key_one': 'abc',
    'key_two': 'def',
    'key_three': 'ghi'
}

b = {
    'key_alpha': 'kappa',
    'key_beta': 'def',
    'key_gamma': 'epsilon'
}
```

Is there an elegant, pythonic way of merging the two dictionnaries by their common value `'def'`?

The result should be:

```
res = {
    'def': ['abc', 'kappa']
}
```

i.e. I'm actually looking for a mapping of `'abc'` to `'kappa'`.

---

Edit: Improved example:

```
a = {
    'key_one': 4,
    'key_two': 'def',
    'key_three': 'ghi'
}

b = {
    'key_alpha': 19,
    'key_beta': 'def',
    'key_gamma': 'epsilon'
}
```

Result:

```
res = {
    'def': [4, 19]
}
```

--> The result allows to map from one identifier to the other.

Comment: Why specifically is that your expected result?

Comment: So you get `res` by letting the value of `key_beta` be the key and the values of `key_alpha` be summarized into a list, while completely ignoring `key_gamma`?

Comment: I don't quite understand how 'def' is the common value resulting in abc, kappa?

Comment: In what sense is 'def' associated with either 'abc' or with 'kappa', based on the dictionaries shown here? I'm not following what you're trying to do.

Comment: In dictionnary `a`, 'abc' is like a primary key. In dictionnary `b`, 'kappa' is like a primary key. Both are actually integers, I'll add an improved example.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense, what does 'def' have to do with what you want to do?  How does 'def' relate to key_one and key_alpha? Why is this the expected outcome?

Comment: @TMOTTM Dictionaries in Python aren't necessarily going to keep the same order you create them in. Having a "primary key" in this fashion as you have described will break a lot and will produce unexpected results.

Comment: This is not how dictionaries work, a dictionary does not have primary key (ordering of key-value pairs is in principle random) so this 'better version' is more confusing then the original one :)

Comment: I think what you really want is a database solution for this

Comment: What is the role of `key_gamma`? Why did you include it in your example?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Just to illustrate that there are more key-value pairs and the dictionnaires are not necessary identically structured.

Comment: @TMOTTM But you've made them identically structured! How are we supposed to infer that `key_alpha` and `key_one` are related but `key_gamma` and `key_three` are not?

Comment: @TMOTTM Please give an example with multiple common values between the two dictionaries and explain what you expect then. Currently, your examples are not enough to generalize a rule.

Comment: where do you define the relation between key_one and key_alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```py
def merge(d1, d2):
    result = {}
    
    # Get the primary keys of each dictionary
    # The primary key will be the first element
    # from the set of keys of each dict
    pk1 = next(iter(d1.keys()))
    pk2 = next(iter(d2.keys()))
    
    # Iterate in parallel for each value
    for v1, v2 in zip(d1.values(), d2.values()):
        if v1 == v2:
            result[v1] = [d1[pk1], d2[pk2]]
            
    return result
```

---

Let's break it down for you to understand.

1. To get the "primary key", I'm using `next(iter(d.keys()))`:

```py
a = {'key_one': 'abc', 'key_two': 'def', 'key_three': 'ghi'}

print(a.keys())
# Outputs dict_keys(['key_one', 'key_two', 'key_three'])

print(next(iter(a.keys())))
# Outputs key_one
```

So `next(iter(d.keys()))` returns the first key inside the dictionary.

2. To iterate in parallel for each dictionary value, I'm using `zip(d1.values(), d2.values())`:

```py
a = {'key_one': 'abc', 'key_two': 'def', 'key_three': 'ghi'}
b = {'key_alpha': 'kappa', 'key_beta': 'def', 'key_gamma': 'epsilon'}

print(a.values())
# Outputs dict_values(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])

print(b.values())
# Outputs dict_values(['kappa', 'def', 'epsilon'])

for va, vb in zip(a.values(), b.values()):
    print(va, vb)
    # Outputs
    #   abc kappa
    #   def def
    #   ghi epsilon
```

Finally, I just compare if both values are equal (note above that, in the second iteration, both values are equal since "def" == "def"). If they are, I add this value (`v1`) as a key to a dictionary (`result`) and assign it to a list (`[...]`) containing the "primary keys" (`[...[pk1], ...[pk2]]`) of each input dictionary (`[d1[pk1], d2[pk2]]`).

Answer (score 0):

> ### THIS IS A Work-in-Progress answer: not completed yet!
>
> What I need first is a more generic example (with at least two/three common values between the two dictionaries. The current example not good enough to generalize any rule and the expected outcome is rather ambiguous.

Try this.

```py
from typing import Dict

def merge(a: Dict, b: Dict) -> Dict:
    avals = list(a.values())
    bvals = list(b.values())
    common_values = set(avals).intersection(bvals)

    res = dict()
    last_aidx = 0
    last_bidx = 0
    for v in common_values:
        aidx = avals.index(v)
        bidx = bvals.index(v)
        res[v] = list(avals[last_aidx:aidx]) + list(bvals[last_bidx:bidx])
        last_aidx = aidx
        last_bidx = bidx

    return res

res = merge(a, b)

# Output of `res`:
# {'def': [4, 19]}
```

### Dummy Data

```py
a = {
    'key_one': 4,
    'key_two': 'def',
    'key_three': 'ghi'
}

b = {
    'key_alpha': 19,
    'key_beta': 'def',
    'key_gamma': 'epsilon'
}
```

Comment: Somebody gave this answer a negative vote! Care to explain why? The answer does exactly what the OP asked in the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think OP wants `{'def': ['abc', 'kappa']}` instead of `{'def': ['key_two', 'key_beta']}`.

Comment: Thanks @enzo. I just realized it. Will fix it.

Comment: @TMOTTM Please give an example with multiple common values between the two dictionaries and explain what you expect then. Currently, your examples are not enough to generalize a rule.

Comment: @CypherX  The two dictionnaries will only have one common value.

Comment: @TMOTTM Ok. Could you please explain, why only `4, 19` are included and not `ghi, epsilon`? Is there any rule for only including values before `def` in each list's values?

Comment: in dicctionnaries `a` and `b`, `def` is a value (of keys `key_two` or `key_beta`, respectively). In the `res` dictionnary, `def` is now a key for the array `[4, 19]`. The `res` dictionnary will be built up as `res = {'def': [4, 19], 'rst': [2, 23], 'uvw': [8, 11]}`.